# print(*args, **kwargs) vs print("{}, {}".format(*args, **kwargs))

Tags: python, string

```
>>> def foo1(*args, **kwargs):
...    print(*args, **kwargs)

>>> def foo2(*args, **kwargs):
...    print("{} {}".format(*args, **kwargs))

>> foo1(1)
1
>> foo2(1)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Is my understanding correct: `*args, **kwargs` is actually a tuple because the comma makes it into one and since there are two placeholders `{}`, then `.format` tries to access the second element of that tuple?

Comment: @thefourtheye: What? No, this is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not true, if this would be true your code would output `"((1) {})"`, because `args` would be a tuple with `1` and `kwargs` an empty dict (which is represented as `{}`).

Generally `func(a,b)` is calling a function with two arguments. This is not the same as calling your function with a tuple `func((a,b))`, you are calling this function only with a single argument.

Sometimes you want to write function which an unknown number of arguments. You can use the `func(*args)` (note that the name `args` is not required, but convention. Any name with a single star in front will work) syntax to do this. We could write a `join()` function that takes not a list of strings but an arbitrary amount of strings as arguments:

```
def join_(*args):
    rv = ""
    for _string in args:
        rv += _string
    return(rv)

>>> join_("first", "second", "third")
"firstsecondthird"

>>> join_(["first", "second", "third"])
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

As you see there is a difference wether you call it with many arguments or with a list of arguments (or tuple, for that matters). If we would have defined it as `def join_(args)` the first version would not have worked, but only the second. The star "sucks" arguments into a single list. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

If there is a way to pull arguments into a list, there should be a way to push arguments out of a list into function arguments. And there is! (assume the definition of `join_()` from above)

```
>>>join_(*["first", "second", "third"])
"firstsecondthird"
```

So a `*` in front of a list (or a tuple) will "push" the elements of the list out to arguments of the function. `**` is the same, just with a dictionary for keyword arguments.

So what does your example do? Lets look at `foo1`. It sucks up all arguments into a list called `args` and then pushes these arguments out again into the print function. So your call `foo1(1)` calls `print(1)`. What does `foo2` do? Your call `foo2(1)` calls `print("{} {}".format(1))` - you are asking to replace to values, but only provided one. Also note that there is no tuple anywhere. What happened to **kwargs? Because you specified no keyword arguments, it "vanished". It is not even an empty dictionary, as you can verify:

```
>>>print(**{})

>>>print({})
{}
```

On another note you can do:

```
def foo3(*args, **kwargs):
    print("{} {}".format(args, kwargs))
```

which will never raise an exception:

```
>>> foo3()
() {}
>>> foo3("abc", "123")
('abc', '123') {}
>>>foo3("foo", c="bar")
('foo',) {'c': 'bar'}
```